# get value from multiple nested json array in flutter

Tags: json, flutter

i want to fetch following JSON in flutter and display it like shown in image or layer wise .
How can i achieve following JSON in flutter
I want to show parent menu name than child menu name than child sub menu name then its products.

```
"parent_menu": [
            {
                "p_category_id": "32",
                "vendor_id": "10",
                "service_id": "1",
                "parent_id": "0",
                "name": "Beverages",
                "image": "",
                "description": "<p>\n\tBeverages</p>\n",
                "priority": "5",
                "status": "Active",
                "parent_name": "Beverages",
                "child_menu": [
                    {
                        "p_category_id": "64",
                        "vendor_id": "10",
                        "service_id": "1",
                        "parent_id": "32",
                        "name": "Vita Coco Coconut Water",
                        "image": "",
                        "description": "",
                        "priority": "0",
                        "status": "Active",
                        "child_name": "Vita Coco Coconut Water",
                        "child_sub_menu": [
                            {
                                "p_category_id": "68",
                                "vendor_id": "10",
                                "service_id": "1",
                                "parent_id": "64",
                                "name": "first sub sub category",
                                "image": "",
                                "description": "",
                                "priority": "3",
                                "status": "Active",
                                "sub_menu": "first sub sub category",
                                "child_name": "Vita Coco Coconut Water",
                                "products": [
                                    {
                                        "product_id": "46",
                                        "vendor_id": "10",
                                        "service_id": "1",
                                        "p_category_id": "68",
                                        "name": "my favorite product",
                                        "description": "",
                                        "amount": "12",
                                        "image": "",
                                        "icon": "",
                                        "is_popular": "No",
                                        "status": "Active",
                                        "date": "2019-05-07 11:04:18"
                                    },
                                    {
                                        "product_id": "56",
                                        "vendor_id": "10",
                                        "service_id": "1",
                                        "p_category_id": "68",
                                        "name": "we",
                                        "description": "<h1>\n\t34</h1>\n",
                                        "amount": "22",
                                        "image": "",
                                        "icon": "",
                                        "is_popular": "No",
                                        "status": "Active",
                                        "date": "2019-05-31 12:04:09"
                                    }
                                ]
                            }
                        ]
                    },
                    {
                        "p_category_id": "43",
                        "vendor_id": "10",
                        "service_id": "1",
                        "parent_id": "32",
                        "name": "coconut water",
                        "image": "",
                        "description": "<p>\n\tere</p>\n",
                        "priority": "1",
                        "status": "Active",
                        "child_name": "coconut water",
                        "child_sub_menu": [
                            {
                                "p_category_id": "69",
                                "vendor_id": "10",
                                "service_id": "1",
                                "parent_id": "43",
                                "name": "coconut water sub1",
                                "image": "",
                                "description": "",
                                "priority": "0",
                                "status": "Active",
                                "sub_menu": "coconut water sub1",
                                "child_name": "coconut water",
                                "products": [
                                    {
                                        "product_id": "47",
                                        "vendor_id": "10",
                                        "service_id": "1",
                                        "p_category_id": "69",
                                        "name": "coconu water with kombucha",
                                        "description": "<p>\n\tit taste very nice</p>\n",
                                        "amount": "22",
                                        "image": "",
                                        "icon": "",
                                        "is_popular": "No",
                                        "status": "Active",
                                        "date": "2019-05-07 12:20:34"
                                    }
                                ]
                            }
                        ]
                    },
                ]
            },
        ],
```

How can i achieve above JSON in flutter
i want to display like this[image]
How can i achieve this in flutter from given JSON and display like this dynamically.

Comment: take a look at this https://medium.com/flutter-community/parsing-complex-json-in-flutter-747c46655f51

Answer (score 0):

```
              class Autogenerated {
                List<ParentMenu> parentMenu;

                Autogenerated({this.parentMenu});

                Autogenerated.fromJson(List <dynamic> jsonList) {
                  if (jsonList!= null) {
                    parentMenu = new List<ParentMenu>();
                    jsonList.forEach((v) {
                      parentMenu.add(new ParentMenu.fromJson(v));
                    });
                  }
                }

                Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
                  final Map<String, dynamic> data = new Map<String, dynamic>();
                  if (this.parentMenu != null) {
                    data['parent_menu'] = this.parentMenu.map((v) => v.toJson()).toList();
                  }
                  return data;
                }
              }

              class ParentMenu {
                String pCategoryId;
                String vendorId;
                String serviceId;
                String parentId;
                String name;
                String image;
                String description;
                String priority;
                String status;
                String parentName;
                List<ChildMenu> childMenu;

                ParentMenu(
                    {this.pCategoryId,
                    this.vendorId,
                    this.serviceId,
                    this.parentId,
                    this.name,
                    this.image,
                    this.description,
                    this.priority,
                    this.status,
                    this.parentName,
                    this.childMenu});

                ParentMenu.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
                  pCategoryId = json['p_category_id'];
                  vendorId = json['vendor_id'];
                  serviceId = json['service_id'];
                  parentId = json['parent_id'];
                  name = json['name'];
                  image = json['image'];
                  description = json['description'];
                  priority = json['priority'];
                  status = json['status'];
                  parentName = json['parent_name'];
                  if (json['child_menu'] != null) {
                    childMenu = new List<ChildMenu>();
                    json['child_menu'].forEach((v) {
                      childMenu.add(new ChildMenu.fromJson(v));
                    });
                  }
                }

                Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
                  final Map<String, dynamic> data = new Map<String, dynamic>();
                  data['p_category_id'] = this.pCategoryId;
                  data['vendor_id'] = this.vendorId;
                  data['service_id'] = this.serviceId;
                  data['parent_id'] = this.parentId;
                  data['name'] = this.name;
                  data['image'] = this.image;
                  data['description'] = this.description;
                  data['priority'] = this.priority;
                  data['status'] = this.status;
                  data['parent_name'] = this.parentName;
                  if (this.childMenu != null) {
                    data['child_menu'] = this.childMenu.map((v) => v.toJson()).toList();
                  }
                  return data;
                }
              }

              class ChildMenu {
                String pCategoryId;
                String vendorId;
                String serviceId;
                String parentId;
                String name;
                String image;
                String description;
                String priority;
                String status;
                String childName;
                List<ChildSubMenu> childSubMenu;

                ChildMenu(
                    {this.pCategoryId,
                    this.vendorId,
                    this.serviceId,
                    this.parentId,
                    this.name,
                    this.image,
                    this.description,
                    this.priority,
                    this.status,
                    this.childName,
                    this.childSubMenu});

                ChildMenu.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
                  pCategoryId = json['p_category_id'];
                  vendorId = json['vendor_id'];
                  serviceId = json['service_id'];
                  parentId = json['parent_id'];
                  name = json['name'];
                  image = json['image'];
                  description = json['description'];
                  priority = json['priority'];
                  status = json['status'];
                  childName = json['child_name'];
                  if (json['child_sub_menu'] != null) {
                    childSubMenu = new List<ChildSubMenu>();
                    json['child_sub_menu'].forEach((v) {
                      childSubMenu.add(new ChildSubMenu.fromJson(v));
                    });
                  }
                }

                Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
                  final Map<String, dynamic> data = new Map<String, dynamic>();
                  data['p_category_id'] = this.pCategoryId;
                  data['vendor_id'] = this.vendorId;
                  data['service_id'] = this.serviceId;
                  data['parent_id'] = this.parentId;
                  data['name'] = this.name;
                  data['image'] = this.image;
                  data['description'] = this.description;
                  data['priority'] = this.priority;
                  data['status'] = this.status;
                  data['child_name'] = this.childName;
                  if (this.childSubMenu != null) {
                    data['child_sub_menu'] =
                        this.childSubMenu.map((v) => v.toJson()).toList();
                  }
                  return data;
                }
              }

              class ChildSubMenu {
                String pCategoryId;
                String vendorId;
                String serviceId;
                String parentId;
                String name;
                String image;
                String description;
                String priority;
                String status;
                String subMenu;
                String childName;
                List<Products> products;

                ChildSubMenu(
                    {this.pCategoryId,
                    this.vendorId,
                    this.serviceId,
                    this.parentId,
                    this.name,
                    this.image,
                    this.description,
                    this.priority,
                    this.status,
                    this.subMenu,
                    this.childName,
                    this.products});

                ChildSubMenu.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
                  pCategoryId = json['p_category_id'];
                  vendorId = json['vendor_id'];
                  serviceId = json['service_id'];
                  parentId = json['parent_id'];
                  name = json['name'];
                  image = json['image'];
                  description = json['description'];
                  priority = json['priority'];
                  status = json['status'];
                  subMenu = json['sub_menu'];
                  childName = json['child_name'];
                  if (json['products'] != null) {
                    products = new List<Products>();
                    json['products'].forEach((v) {
                      products.add(new Products.fromJson(v));
                    });
                  }
                }

                Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
                  final Map<String, dynamic> data = new Map<String, dynamic>();
                  data['p_category_id'] = this.pCategoryId;
                  data['vendor_id'] = this.vendorId;
                  data['service_id'] = this.serviceId;
                  data['parent_id'] = this.parentId;
                  data['name'] = this.name;
                  data['image'] = this.image;
                  data['description'] = this.description;
                  data['priority'] = this.priority;
                  data['status'] = this.status;
                  data['sub_menu'] = this.subMenu;
                  data['child_name'] = this.childName;
                  if (this.products != null) {
                    data['products'] = this.products.map((v) => v.toJson()).toList();
                  }
                  return data;
                }
              }

              class Products {
                String productId;
                String vendorId;
                String serviceId;
                String pCategoryId;
                String name;
                String description;
                String amount;
                String image;
                String icon;
                String isPopular;
                String status;
                String date;

                Products(
                    {this.productId,
                    this.vendorId,
                    this.serviceId,
                    this.pCategoryId,
                    this.name,
                    this.description,
                    this.amount,
                    this.image,
                    this.icon,
                    this.isPopular,
                    this.status,
                    this.date});

                Products.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
                  productId = json['product_id'];
                  vendorId = json['vendor_id'];
                  serviceId = json['service_id'];
                  pCategoryId = json['p_category_id'];
                  name = json['name'];
                  description = json['description'];
                  amount = json['amount'];
                  image = json['image'];
                  icon = json['icon'];
                  isPopular = json['is_popular'];
                  status = json['status'];
                  date = json['date'];
                }

                Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
                  final Map<String, dynamic> data = new Map<String, dynamic>();
                  data['product_id'] = this.productId;
                  data['vendor_id'] = this.vendorId;
                  data['service_id'] = this.serviceId;
                  data['p_category_id'] = this.pCategoryId;
                  data['name'] = this.name;
                  data['description'] = this.description;
                  data['amount'] = this.amount;
                  data['image'] = this.image;
                  data['icon'] = this.icon;
                  data['is_popular'] = this.isPopular;
                  data['status'] = this.status;
                  data['date'] = this.date;
                  return data;
                }
              }
```

Try to this  You can get your model class